# Menu Click to .hide() and then .show() using jQuery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I'm trying to use a submenu to hide and show separate divs. It works for the hide but the doesn't recognize the show. Tips or advice would be welcome. jQuery Code Below:

```
$('nav div').click(function(){
    $($branding).css("display", "none");
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('nav div.active').click(function(){
    $($branding).css("display", "block");
    $(this).removeClass();
});
```

Comment: instead of `.css("display", "none")` just do `.hide()` or `.show()` what is the case where `.show()` doesn't work?

Comment: What's in `$branding`?

Comment: @Adijit - when i click on the menu item it hides the appropriate content but when i go to click again to show it again(reset) it doesn't respond.

Comment: @Dhaval - $branding is a var just to call a couple classes of divs

Comment: @jeffrey_powers try doing `.toggle()`. Also, what are you declaring `$branding` as? if it looks like `$branding = $('.branding');` then all you need to do is `$branding.toggle()` instead of `$($branding)`

Comment: @Bongs answer is a good one.  But to explain the actual issue, handlers are bound at the time the code is executed.  When your code executes the element does not have the `.active` class, so that handler is not bound.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are doing it right, just the few changes:

```
$('nav div').on("click",function(){
$($branding).css("display", "none");
$(this).addClass('active');
 });

  $('nav div.active').on("click",function(){
$($branding).css("display", "block");
$(this).removeClass('active');
 });
```

This should help you.

Comment: This is exactly the same as the original code.  Changing `click` to `.on("click",` changes nothing.

Comment: Yeah it still doesn't honor the second segment of the code.

Comment: @JamesMontagne if you look closely then you find, $(this).removeClass('active'); is missing in the given code. jeffrey_powers has missed this and instead of this he has written only $(this).removeClass();. Have you checked the code, or just downvote me?

Comment: @NaveenChandraTiwari You are right about the missing `"active"` and you should explain that.  However, this will not work.  When your handlers are bound there is no `nav div.active` to bind to.  Similarly, once you add the `active` class the original hanlder will not be unbound.  The first handler will always fire.

Comment: @jeffrey_powers You  did not include jquery in your fiddle so it couldn't work at all:  http://jsfiddle.net/p2hn4/2/

Comment: @NaveenChandraTiwari On 2nd thought, you're actually wrong about `removeClass` as well.  If you have a look at the documentation the class name is optional  http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `toggle()` function.  http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Example code

HTML

```
<button>Toggle 'em</button>
<p>Hiya</p>
<p>Such interesting text, eh?</p>
```

jQuery

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).toggle().toggleClass('active');
});
```

In your case the code would be something like:

```
$('nav div').click(function(){
  $($branding).toggle().toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that handlers are bound at the time the code is executed.  When your code executes the element does not have the `.active` class, so that handler is not bound.

One solution would be to bind the handler to the `nav` and then use event delegation to affect the element correctly in the current state.  Something like this:

```
$('nav').on('click', 'div:not(.active)', function(){
    $($branding).css("display", "none");
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('nav').on('click', 'div.active', function(){
    $($branding).css("display", "block");
    $(this).removeClass();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p2hn4/3/

That being said, in this case delegation is not your best solution, though I thought it worth explaining.  You should consider using `toggle` as suggested in another answer.

You can read more about event delegation in the [`on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).